# spark 1.6.1 python 3.5.1 building naive bayes classifier

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, naivebayes

My question is based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231049/how-to-use-spark-naive-bayes-classifier-for-text-classification-with-idf).

1. Would it be possible more detailed comments/explain code starting
   line `tf = HashingTF().transform( training_raw.map(lambda doc:
   doc["text"], preservesPartitioning=True))`
2. How could I print the confusion matrix?
3. What does below error mean? How can I fix it? The model still gets built and I get predictions

   `>>> # Train and check
   ... model = NaiveBayes.train(training)
   [Stage 2:=============================>                             (2 + 2) / 4]16/04/05 18:18:28 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
   16/04/05 18:18:28 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS`
4. How could I print results for the new observation. I tried and
   failed

   `>>> model.predict("love")
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\mllib\classification.py", line 594, in predict
       x = _convert_to_vector(x)
     File "c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\mllib\linalg\__init__.py", line 77, in _convert_to_vector
       raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
   TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'str'> into Vector`

Comment: Could you add  a sample from `training_raw`?

Comment: the data is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231049/how-to-use-spark-naive-bayes-classifier-for-text-classification-with-idf

Answer (score 2):

1.hashingTF in spark is similiar to the scikitlearn HashingVectorizer. training_raw is an rdd of text.For a detailed explanation of the available vectorizers in pySpark see [Vectorizers](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.feature.HashingTF). For a complete example see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231049/how-to-use-spark-naive-bayes-classifier-for-text-classification-with-idf?lq=1)

2.BLAS is the Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms library. You can check out this page on github for a potential  [solution](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/issues/124).

3.You are trying to use model.predict on a string ("love"). You must first convert the string to a vector. A simple example that takes a dense vector string and outputs a dense vector with label is

```
def parseLine(line):
    parts = line.split(',')
    label = float(parts[0])
    features = Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in parts[1].split(' ')])
    return LabeledPoint(label, features)
```

You are probably looking for a sparse vector. So try Vectors.sparse.

Comment: for 2, I understand what BLAS stands for now. But would it be possible to provide tips to get rid of the error? Also let me know how to print the confusion matrix...thanks