# Handling continuous data in Spark NaiveBayes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

As per official documentation of Spark NaiveBayes:

> It supports Multinomial NB (see here) which can handle finitely
>   supported discrete data.

How can I handle continuous data (for example: percentage of some in some document ) in Spark NaiveBayes?

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation can process only binary features so for good result you'll have to discretize and encode your data. For discretization you can use either [`Buketizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#bucketizer) or [`QuantileDiscretizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer). The former one is less expensive and might be a better fit when you want to use some domain specific knowledge.

For encoding you can use dummy encoding using [`OneHotEncoder`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder). with adjusted `dropLast` `Param`.

So overall you'll need:

- `QuantileDiscretizer` or `Bucketizer` -> `OneHotEncoder` for each continuous feature.
- `StringIndexer`* -> `OneHotEncoder` for each discrete feature.
- `VectorAssembler` to combine all of the above.

* Or predefined column metadata.