# Addressing categorical features with one hot encoding and vector assembler vs vector indexer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, categorical-data, apache-spark-ml

Say I have categorical features in a dataframe. In order to do ML on the dataframe, I do one hot encoding on the categorical columns using `OneHotEncoderEstimator()` and then use `VectorAssembler()` to assemble all the features to a single column. When reading the Spark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#decision-tree-regression) I've seen the use of `VectorIndexer()` to index categorical features in a features vector column. If I have already performed one hot encoding on the categorical columns before formulating the features vector column, is there any point in applying the `VectorIndexer()` on it.

Comment: Whoever is down voting the question, can you please specify the reason for the down vote

Comment: Your question is way too broad (please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)); this sounds exactly like a question where you should have done the experiment you describe verbally, and if still having *coding* issues/questions, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. I have done experiments and it doesn't seem to make a difference with or without VectorIndexer, (at least in my case). I just wanted to know the opinion from someone who has a better understanding of the specifics. I know that there is a downside to the indexed variables compared to the OHE because of ranking.

Comment: You are very welcome to share your experiments here, instead of expecting us to re-create them from scratch based only on what we may have understood (or not) from your verbal description. Notice also that SO is not meant for *opinion*-based questions...

Answer (score 2):

`OneHotEncoder(Estimator)` and `VectorIndexer` are quite different beasts and are not exchangeable. `OneHotEncoder(Estimator)` is used primarily when the downstream process uses a linear model ([it can be also used with Naive Bayes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45626754/10465355)).

Let's consider a simple `Dataset`

```
val df = Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).toDF
```

and a `Pipeline`

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._

val m1 = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new OneHotEncoderEstimator()
   .setInputCols(Array("value")).setOutputCols(Array("features"))
)).fit(df)
```

If such model is applied to our data it will be [one-hot-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable#Categorical_variables_and_regression) (depending on a configuration `OneHotEncoderEstimator` supports both one-hot-encoding and dummy encoding) - in other words each level, excluding reference will be represented as a separate binary column:

```
m1.transform(df).schema("features").metadata
```

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata = {"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"binary":[{"idx":0,"name":"0"},{"idx":1,"name":"1"},{"idx":2,"name":"2"}]},"num_attrs":3}}
```

Please note that such representation is inefficient and impractical to use with algorithms which handle categorical features natively.

In contrast, `VectorIndexer` only analyzes the data, and adjust metadata accordingly

```
val m2 = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("value")).setOutputCol("raw"),
  new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("raw").setOutputCol("features")
)).fit(df)

m2.transform(df).schema("features").metadata
```

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata = {"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"nominal":[{"ord":false,"vals":["1.0","2.0","3.0"],"idx":0,"name":"value"}]},"num_attrs":1}}
```

In other words it is more or less equivalent to a vectorized variant of [`StringIndexer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) (you can achieve a similar result, with more control over the output, using a set of `StringIndexers` followed by `VectorAssembler`).

Such features are [unsuitable for linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115049/why-do-we-need-to-dummy-code-categorical-variables), but are valid input for decision trees and tree ensembles.

To summarize - in practice `OneHotEncoder(Esitmator)` and `VectorIndexer` are mutually exclusive and the choice, of which one should be used, depends on the downstream process.